# How to search for a value, if found enter in specific text in the cell to the right and loop to the end

Tags: vba, excel, search, foreach

I am looking to check an entire column for a certain value (first one being Murphy, Yvonne), if that value is found then put something (Team name) in the cell next to where that value is found, continuing through the entire list. Leaving spaces where the searched for value is not found.

Ultimately I would like to do a few of these statements to populate the entire column with team names (team 1,2,3 etc.)

I have been searching around and playing with the code (mind you I only dabble in VBA from time to time) and I was able to get to the below. Which does the search and enters the team name in a cell but it doesn't enter it in the cell next to where the match was found.  It just keeps adding the team name one after another for each match of the searched for term.

Do I need to store the range value somewhere and then tell it to insert the team name at that location?

Thanks for your help

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim irow As Integer

irow = 2
For Each i In Range("i2:i500")  
    If i.value = "Murphy, Yvonne" Then  
        Cells(irow, 11) = "Team Name"  
        irow = irow + 1  
    End If  
Next i  

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

We need to change **irow** to match the desired row:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim irow As Integer
    For Each i In Range("i2:i500")
        If i.Value = "Murphy, Yvonne" Then
            irow = i.Row
            Cells(irow, 11) = "Team Name"
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1**

For **2** criteria**

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim irow As Integer
irow = 2
For Each I In Range("i2:i500")
    If I.Value = "Murphy, Yvonne" And _
        I.Offset(0, -1).Value = "Good, Thomas" Then
            irow = I.Row
            Cells(irow, 10).Value = "Team Name"
    End If
Next I
End Sub
```

Comment: OK so what if I need to it to check two criteria in different columns but I still want it to iterate down the list to 500? <br>



Using the example above: OK we check 12:i500 for "Murphy, Yvonne" AND h2:h500 for "Good, Thomas" then enter "team name"

Would I have to start with the above statement and in the "then" section put another "for each"?

Thanks again!

Comment: It depends on whether **both** criteria need to be *True* or **either/or**

Comment: Both need to be true.